# Don't make functions within a loop no-loop-func Axios Request async await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios, es6-promise

I have an axios request file that goes and gets many requests which I used an async function around it all so that I could delay the requests per second sent to an api (their rate limit).

My code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const litecoinApi = async (addresses, resolve, reject) => {
  let addressesBalance = {};
  let addressRequests = [];

  addresses.forEach(address => {
    addressRequests.push("https://api.blockchair.com/litecoin/dashboards/address/" + address);
  });

  function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
    });
  }

  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < addressRequests.length; i++) {
    await axios.get(addressRequests[i])
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data);
      const data = res.data.data[addresses[i]];
      console.log('data', data.address.balance);
      addressesBalance[addresses[i]] = data.address.balance / 100000000;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    await delay();
  }

  resolve(addressesBalance);


  // let i;
  // for (i = 0; i < addressRequests.length; i++) {
  //   await axios.get(addressRequests[i])
  //   .then((res) => {
  //     const data = res.data.data;
  //     console.log(data);
  //     addressesBalance[data.address.toString()] = data.confirmed_balance.toString();
  //   }).catch((err) => {
  //     console.log(err.response);
  //   });
  //   await delay();
  // }

  // resolve(addressesBalance);
};
```

I am simply accessing the request and going through the object to receive the (address balance).

I am getting the warning in the console:

```
./src/apis/litecoin.js
  Line 20:  Don't make functions within a loop  no-loop-func
```

The problem I'm having is that line 20:

```
.then((res) => {
```

Is actually not the problem, it is clearly line 22:

```
const data = res.data.data[addresses[i]];
```

addresses is simply an array of strings. When I remove accessing the key addresses[i] from the object res.data.data the warning goes away. The object res.data.data in console is:

```
{LWcXUB6ny88tK49TK1V6KprE5oDcJ1zJhx: {…}}
   LWcXUB6ny88tK49TK1V6KprE5oDcJ1zJhx:
      address:
         {type: null, script_hex: "", balance: 0, balance_usd: 0, received: 0, …}
      transactions:
         []
```

So the litecoin address LWcXUB6ny88tK49TK1V6KprE5oDcJ1zJhx is the key in an object and the value is another object with address and transactions as keys. My final goal is the balance in the value of the address key.

I left a commented for loop below (which was for a slightly different api) because I don't get the warning in that one. The problem is there is simply no way to access the value of the litecoin address key without how you would normally access a key in an object.

I have changed this line:

```
const data = res.data.data[addresses[i]];
```

To:

```
const data = res.data.data;
const address = Object.keys(data);
```

As soon as I attempt Object.keys I get the error let alone actually accessing the first key:

```
address[0]
```

This leaves me at a complete loss because then I literally can't access the object without getting the error that I am using a loop in a function.

The resolve and reject are from a promise that this function gets called in and I use the async function to wait until all the api requests are done before I resolve the promise that this function is in.

That promise then goes out and sets my state correctly.

Anyone have any ideas? I have looked at many other SO however no one seems to be dealing with the problem I am here. I honestly don't see how I am using a function at all in the loop.

Accessing a key in an object certainly isn't a function that I know.

The:

```
.then((res) => {
   ...
}
```

Is simply waiting for the axios.get promise. This get / then cycle has worked in other api requests without this issue. Plus the warning really only happens when attempting to pass a key into an object inside the for loop.

I should let you know everything works correctly with the warning. It just infuriates me that I can't get rid of this warning.

Thank you very much for your time and insight.

Comment: Declare the function outside of the loop, and put the reference to `then`'s argument. Alternatively opt out _no-loop-func_ in the linter's configuration.

Comment: If I declare my async function outside the for loop I can't use await within the for loop then can I? Or are you saying put the axios request in a function outside the loop then call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the advice of Teemu ( if you want to re-post this answer i'll give you the answer ).

I tried this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const litecoinApi = async (addresses, resolve, reject) => {
  let addressesBalance = {};
  let addressRequests = [];

  addresses.forEach(address => {
    addressRequests.push("https://api.blockchair.com/litecoin/dashboards/address/" + address);
  });

  function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
    });
  }

  function axiosRequest(addressRequests, addresses) {
    axios.get(addressRequests)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data);
      const data = res.data.data[addresses];
      console.log('data', data.address.balance);
      addressesBalance[addresses] = data.address.balance / 100000000;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < addressRequests.length; i++) {
    await axiosRequest(addressRequests[i], addresses[i]);
    await delay();
  }

  resolve(addressesBalance);
};
```

Which simply moves the axios request into its own function that is then passed the requests and addresses.

The await cannot work within the axiosRequest() function but you can still use it in the for loop solving the problem.

This solved my problem thank you very much Teemu!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something simple and single process at the time:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const litecoinApi = async (addresses) => {
    const balance = {};

    for (const address of addresses) {
        const currentAddress = `https://api.blockchair.com/litecoin/dashboards/address/${address}`;
        const result =  await axios.get(currentAddress)
        const data = result.data.data[address];
        console.log(data);
        balance[address] = data.address.balance / 100000000;
    }

    return balance;
}
```

Or you can process all requests in parallel with:

```
const result = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Oh good point just also with the await delay() promise function though so that I can stay below the request limit. Without the delay this could go faster than the api is willing to let me do requests depending on how quick the response is.

Thanks for the answer!